# GNU `sem` not seeming to block properly

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-sem

I wrote a `bash` script to use GNU `sem` to download multiple files simultaneously with `aria2` and then beep when it is done.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="${1:-files.txt}" # default input file is files.txt

dflag=0
#currdir=''

while read -r line
do
    if [ "$line" ] # skip blank lines
    then
        if [[ "$line" =~ (https?|ftp)\:\/\/ ]]
        then
            if [ $dflag -eq 1 ]
            then
                dflag=0
            fi
            echo "URL: '$line'"
            # -j N Run up to N commands in parallel
            # -j +0 is useful as it will run number-of-cpu-cores jobs simultaneously
            sem --no-notice -j +0 aria2c --file-allocation=none -c -x10 -j10 -d \"$currdir\" \"$line\"
        else
            echo "Directory: '$line'"
            if [ $dflag -eq 1 ]
            then
                currdir="${currdir}/${line}"
            else
                #currdir=''
                currdir="$line"
                dflag=1
            fi
            echo "$currdir"
            if [ ! -d "$currdir" ]
            then
                mkdir -p "$currdir"
            fi
        fi
    fi
done < "$filename"
sem --wait # waits until all jobs are done
echo -en "\007"; echo -en "\007"; echo -en "\007"
```

My script is working fine except that it beeps long before the job finishes. I thought the script blocks until the loop is done but it is not doing that. If I try a simple test script, it works as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do
  sem --no-notice -j +0 echo $i
done
sem --wait
echo -en "\007"; echo -en "\007"; echo -en "\007"
```

So what do I do to make the 'real' script work properly?

BTW I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.3.27(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0)`.

Comment: What is the reason why you do not run --bibtex once?

Comment: Are you Ole Tange, the developer of `parallel`? The message says `To silence this citation notice run 'parallel --bibtex' once or use '--no-notice'.` So I chose the second method. Does it make any difference? I tried the first method and I get `Type: 'will cite' and press enter. >` and then have to type `will cite`, which is really an annoyance while I am trying to run or debug this script. BTW it still doesn't block.  Meanwhile, why isn't the script blocking in this case? If anyone should be able to determine this, it is you. :)

Comment: Why? As it says: you only need to run 'parallel --bibtex' once. If you can change the script to a script that I can run, it will be helpful. I do not have neither aria2c nor your inputfile. For better help try: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#REPORTING-BUGS

Comment: I guess the question is, why would you ask me the same, IMO, pushy, irrelevant question twice instead of addressing the REAL question, and why would you make users jump through hoops like that to advertise your utility? I have never used a single utility in decades that demanded that…

Comment: I ask out of curiosity: Why not do --bibtex a single time and be done with it, instead of --no-notice every single time? Sorry if it feels pushy, but I am genuinely curious why. The reason for the behaviour was discussed on the email list: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/parallel/2013-11/msg00006.html Your original question will be probably be possible to answer, if you follow gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#REPORTING-BUGS

Comment: OK,OK. I have more information now that I have been testing. I found that the script blocks only if there are more files than there are jobs. As soon as the number of files remaining is less than the number of jobs, the block releases and the script continues on after the beeps. Is this a bug? I don't know but it is unexpected behavior (to me anyway).